# Q: Loop in Google Apps Script Error: Cannot read property "length" of undefined

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

I got the `Error: Cannot read property length of undefined` and dont quite      understand the problem.

From the other posts of stackoverflow I figured out that the function cannot determinate the length of the parsed Object.

What I am doing is the following:

I do import historical data of e.g. google stock price with `=Index(GOOGLEFINANCE("NASDAQ:GOOG";"price";HEUTE()-60;HEUTE());;2)` into my spreadsheet. 
Then I calculate the 21 simple moving average from the data with `=average(A128:A148)`.

Now I compare the stockprice and the 21 SMA to determinate if the Stockprice is above or under the 21 SMA. So far so good.

Last I try to write a function that counts the days above the 21 SMA starting from the latest Value.

```
function daysabove(input){
var output = 0;
for (var i = input.length-1;i>= 0;i--){ 
if (input[i][0]=="over" ){
 if (input[i+1][0]=="under"){
output++;
   break;
 }
 else {
 output++;
        }
    } ` 
else  {
  output--;
     } 
}
   return output;}
```

On the spreadsheet i call that function with `=daysabove(C129:C148)` . C129 to C148 containing either above or under.

Edit: I even tried to run the function on a range that contain manually written "above" & "under" so that there is no connection to google finance. Still doesnt work.

So getting back to the question: The length or the object should be defined. Whats wrong here?

Comment: You can't use Google Finance programmatically. You didn't read the documentation of the finance functions.

Comment: THx for the reply, i tested that by just writing down 21values of  "under" & "above" in a column and did parse this range as inputto the formula. That didnt work either. So i shouldnt be connected with google finance. Thx though for the information aber finance. didint know that. Makes google finance kinda unreliable

Comment: in the spreadsheet its calld `property[0] from undefined` and in the scripteditor it is `property length of undefined` . So thats not the same error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error: Cannot read property length of undefined

This occurs , because `input` is undefined, when called from the script editor and doesn't have a length property, because you don't pass any value as input to the `function daysabove`.

---

> Error: Cannot read property[0] from undefined

This occurs because `i+1` evaluates to out of the index range. Say, You execute `=daysabove(C1:C4)`. C1:C4 will all be "over".

```
for (var i = input.length-1;i>= 0;i--){ 
if (input[i][0]=="over" ){
 if (input[i+1][0]=="under"){
```

`input.length` will be 4;
`input.length-1` will be 3;
 `i` is initialized as 3;
Note that in javascript arrays, the first element's index is 0;
index of ["over","over","over","over"] from front to back is 0,1,2,3 respectively;
`input[i][0]` == `input[3][0]` will be the last element in C1:C4;
The next statement calls for i+1,i.e., `input[4]` ,which is `undefined`. Undefined is not a array. Hence we cannot read the property [0] of undefined.
If you're gonna do a bottoms-up loop, then make sure everything is reverse. So, your loop can be fixed by  using `input[i-1][0]` as the next statement and changing for-condition to `i>0`. There are other syntax errors too. Consider reviewing [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and taking a [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js)

---

Regardless,
As written in the [Official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281),

> Historical data cannot be downloaded or accessed via the Sheets API or **Apps Script.**  If you attempt to do so, you will see a #N/A error in place of the values in the corresponding cells of your spreadsheet.

Your script will fail in any case,as it references historical google finance data.

---

If you just want to count the number of days above-days under, use

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C4,"over")-COUNTIF(C1:C4,"under")
```

Comment: thank you for all the information. This was very helpful although `=COUNTIF(C1:C4,"over")-COUNTIF(C1:C4,"under")` is not working as intended. 

`=countif(C$128:C128;C128)` was pretty close but also insufficent. I need something that counts until a value changes (from "above" to "under" or vise verca) , then set the counter to 0 and starts counting from there. 
`=countif(C$128:C128;C128)` counts the given values in a range and doesnt mind the reset to 0. 

( src: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3919-excel-count-cells-until-value-changes.html)  Any suggestions anyone?